# Why my code go on when I delete window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
    db.collection("chatroom").where("who", "array-contains-any", [Myuid, Selleruid]).get().then((result) => {
  db.collection('chatroom').add(data)
  window.location.href = "/chat.html"
  })
```

this is part of my code that add a chatroom db to firebase server. It doesn't work, but when I delete window.location.href = "/chat.html" , then it could add data. I can't understand why it works after delete it, and why it doesn't work with that window ~ line.

Comment: Because you are navigating away from your page before the `.add` even had a chance to finish executing, since you are not awaiting the promise it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `add()` starts an asynchronous write operation, which happens in the background (to prevent blocking the browser). Your `window.location.href = "/chat.html"` statement however runs right away, so the write operation gets aborted before it can complete.

To fix this, you'll want to wait for the write operation to be completed before navigating away:

```
db.collection('chatroom').add(data).then(() => {
  window.location.href = "/chat.html"
})
```